# resizing the image within the table in mobile query doesn't work

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3, media-queries

I have an image inside the table's `<td>` i want to resize it if the screen size is in mobile size. Also i already added viewport. My mobile query works fine in other's purpose except the img.
Here is my html:

```
<table class="table borderless">
      <tr>
      <td align="center" width="10%"> <img width="55%" class="img" src="images/save energy.png"></td>
      <td><h4>Save on Energy Costs</h4>
          <p class="pindent">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</p>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td align="center" width="10%"> <img width="55%" class="img" src="images/save environment.png"></td>
      <td><h4>Save the Environment</h4>
          <p class="pindent">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</p>
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
```

Here is my mobile query css :

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    table {
        width:95%;
    }
    .custom-box{
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .margin-box {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .cust-box {
    margin-left: 0px;
    }
    .carousel-inner{
     max-height: 500px !important;
    }
    .img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-: -moz-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
    }
    .img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-: rotate(360deg);;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    } 
}
```

Comment: have you used the `viewport meta tag`?

Comment: On your media query. There's no width defined. Something like this (width: 30% !important)

Comment: i aready used meta tag viewport . I have also put width. the .img {

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i don't really understand what you mean by `i want to resize it` , but i guess you want it to make it `100%` not `55%` how it's set in the inline CSS

so in the media query add `width:100%` on the the `.image` so it will overwrite the `width:55%` .

or you can set whatever width you want to the image

see snippet below or [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mypkuzxk/)

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    table {
        width:95%;
    }
    .custom-box{
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .margin-box {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .cust-box {
    margin-left: 0px;
    }
    .carousel-inner{
     max-height: 500px !important;
    }
    .img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-: -moz-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
    width:100%!important;
    }
    .img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-: rotate(360deg);;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    } 
}
```

```html
<table class="table borderless">
      <tr>
      <td align="center" width="10%"> <img width="55%" class="img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></td>
      <td><h4>Save on Energy Costs</h4>
          <p class="pindent">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</p>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td align="center" width="10%"> <img width="55%" class="img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></td>
      <td><h4>Save the Environment</h4>
          <p class="pindent">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</p>
         
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
```

or you could make the `td` in which the image is located, bigger and so the image will get bigger

see snippet below or [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/mypkuzxk/1/)

```css
@media (max-width: 600px) {
    table {
        width:95%;
    }
    .custom-box{
        margin-left: 10px;
        margin-right: 10px;
    }
    .margin-box {
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .cust-box {
    margin-left: 0px;
    }
    .carousel-inner{
     max-height: 500px !important;
    }
    .img {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
    border-radius: 50%;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    -moz-: -moz-transform .8s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform .8s ease-in-out;
    width:100%!important;
    }
    .img:hover {
    -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg);
    -moz-: rotate(360deg);;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
    } 
    td:first-child { width:40%}
}
```

```html
<table class="table borderless">
      <tr>
      <td align="center" width="10%"> <img width="55%" class="img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></td>
      <td><h4>Save on Energy Costs</h4>
          <p class="pindent">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</p>
      </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
      <td align="center" width="10%"> <img width="55%" class="img" src="http://placehold.it/350x150"></td>
      <td><h4>Save the Environment</h4>
          <p class="pindent">TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST TEST</p>
         
      </td>
      </tr>
      </table>
```

Comment: sir i already added. Look here .img {
    max-width: 100% !important;

Comment: you added `max-width` . add `width` because in HTML you set `width:55%` so you must overwrite it by using the same property, WIDTH not max-width

Comment: also i already added in width: 100% !important. nothing happens sir

Comment: can you make a jsfiddle to show me ? it should work as it works in my example

Comment: i'll screenshot sir

Comment: screenshot doesn't help me. i need to see what code are you using. because in my answer, `width:100%` it's working, and you say that in your project, it's not working. so it must be something to do with the code